# How to check client performance for webgl(three.js)

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, webgl, gpu

I have a graphic project using three.JS and now I want to check client GPU performance automatically and compute how many elements I can load in application. I think about something like a GPU benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/), [this THREEX plugin](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/06/25/monitor-rendering-performance-within-threejs/) and [webgl inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/).

Comment: thanks, but this plugin checks performance after scene creation and I need to check performance before it. It helps me to know for example how many objects or faces I can load on client.